# assignment and comparison pointers in c

Tags: c, pointers, function-pointers, void, void-pointers

I am getting an error in my partition function that reads:

```
assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast 
v= array[low]; 

comparison between pointer and integer [-Werror]
```

These are the error I'm getting throughout the partition function. Please help.

```
void quickSort(void *array[], int low, int high)
{
    int p;
    if(low < high)
    {
        p= partition(*array, low, high);
        quickSort(array, low, p-1);
        quickSort(array, p+1, high);
    }
} 

int partition(void *array[], int low, int high)
{
    int v, i, j, temp;
    v= array[low];
    i=low;
    j=high+1;
    do
    {
        do 
            i++;
        while(array[i]<v && i <=high);
        do 
            j--;
        while(v<array[j]);

        if(i<j)
        {
            temp =array[i];
            array[i] = array[j];
            array[j] = temp;
        }
    }while(i<j);

    array[low] = array[high];
    array[high] = v;

    return(j);
}
```

Comment: `array` is an array of pointers to `void`. What are  you expecting to get by assigning a pointer to `void` to an integer?

Comment: `int partition(void *array[], int low, int high);
    {`  is not valid code.  Post true code and its use.

Comment: what do you mean its not true code? that is the prototype i was given and i cant change it.

Answer (score 1):

`array` is an array of pointers, so `array[low]` is a pointer; you can't meaningfully compare this with the integer in `v`. You need to dereference the pointers to get to the values. And to access them as `int` this you need to cast the pointer type.

```
v = *(int*)array[low];
```

All the other uses of `array` need to be modified similarly, e.g.

```
while (*(int*)array[i] < v && i <= high)
```

Answer (score 0):

> assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast

Comes from this line `v= array[low];`

This is because `array` is an array of `void` pointers (i.e. `array[low]` is also a `void`pointer) and v is an `int`. So looking at types you are doing

```
int = void*
```

so as the error says - you have a pointer (void pointer) and makes an int from the pointer. That is illegal.

> comparison between pointer and integer [-Werror]

comes from these lines:

```
while(array[i]<v && i <=high);
....
while(v<array[j]);
```

The reason is same as described above - you mix int type with pointer type.

I'm not sure what you should do to solve but maybe the array shall be casted and dereferenced as `int`. Like

```
v= array[low];  ---->  v= *((int*)array[low]);
                            |^^^^^^^^^^^^^^|
                              cast void* to get an int*
                          |-----------------|
                           Dereference the int* to get an int
```

Similar for the two `while` statements.

That said, I see other things in your code that looks strange to me.

For instance:

```
array[high] = v;
```

I'm not sure what you are trying here but again there is a type mismatch.